# How to use Text as texture on Cube inside papervision3d?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, textures, papervision3d

What is the best technique to apply anti-aliased text as texture on cube using papervision3d?

1. make dynamic textfield, convert it to moviematerial then apply it to the faces of cube.
2. Design a bitmap using any picture editor and make a bitmapFileMaterial to apply on faces of cube.
3. Any other suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create your text field and set its content.
var t:TextField = new TextField();
t.text = "Hello world!";

// create a BitmapData of your wished width and height
var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100,100);

// Fill bmp with the content of your TextField. 
//It's as if you took a picture of t.
bitmap.draw(t);
// Create a material with the resulting BitmapData and you can use it on any DisplayObject3D!
var material:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial(bitmap);
material.smooth = true;
material.doubleSided = true;

// Create cube
var cube:Cube = new Cube(material)
```

Comment: Cube takes MaterialList not material. Thanks anyway. I will give it a try